# Construction of a increasing increasing function with 4 different Dini derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous increasing function with different Dini derivatives at 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117582/continuous-increasing-function-with-different-dini-derivatives-at-0)

Is there a way to construct an *increasing* function $f\colon [-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that none of the four Dini derivatives $D^{\pm}$ and $D_{\pm}$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative for a definition) are equal at $0$?