# Differentiability of a monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that if  $f : [0;1] \to {\mathbb R}$ is a nondecreasing function, then the set 
$E$ of points where $f$ is not differentiable has Lebesgue measure zero. Is there an example where $E$ is not countable ?
.

Comment: Brian M. Scott gave you the standard example. For more than you probably want to know about this topic, see my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117582/

Comment: Thanks for the references Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a standard example.

Comment: Of course, where was my mind?

Answer (score 1):

You could find a whole chapter devoted to this topic, with lots of examples and counterexamples in the book http://books.google.fr/books/about/A_first_course_in_Sobolev_spaces.html?id=W3RLWwnY0RkC&redir_esc=y